# Running php in node on Heroku

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, npm

I know this is very wrong.  I have a project running on node on Heroku.  I have a php script that is long and complex and I don't want to rewrite it.  I was going to setup another server but that would cause some CORS/XSS problems.

My question is, is it possible to run a small php script in Node on Heroku?

I know this is bad practice but it is a one time thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this by default, because when you deploy a node app you'll be using the Node buildpack from Heroku. What you can do instead is this:

Write your PHP script as a web API, and deploy this to it's own Heroku app. Then, in your Node app, make an HTTP call to your PHP API on Heroku so it does what you want =)

Comment: no need to deploy the php code on its separate heroku app. we can deploy both on the single heroku app but with 2 buildpacks.